# Markdown for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, markdownsharp

I'm looking for a basic markdown component for ASP.NET MVC and Razor. I don't need anything fancy or particularly extensible, it just needs to play nice with MVC and be compatible with the BSD License.

(A NuGet package is a definite plus.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Markdown Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) used by stackoverflow?

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MarkdownSharp